# How to Make diagonal rectangle with the flat Bottom?

Tags: html, css

Ok, So here's my Problem. I have a made a Diagonal Shape on my webpage like in the Image Below:
[image: As Seen In the Image, I have a Shape Which Can Contain Text, Images, etc.]

Now What I need is something like this:
[image: I need a Shape like a shape created by the blue dotted outline.]

I need a Shape like the one created by the blue dotted outline. Now I have tried changing and moving around the values of the First Shape but still wasn't able to get any success. **Please Noe that the Two shapes - the already existing shape and the one Outlined by the Dotted line's - must be two different shapes.**

Hope Someone can Help me Accomplish this. Also, I can not have any space between the bottom of the first shape and the one I want to draw.

Here is my Code (HTML and CSS) for the already exising shape:

```css
.BeginToday9 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-left: 425px;
  padding-right: 425px;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(5deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(5deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(5deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(5deg);
  transform: skewY(5deg);
}

.BeginToday9>.wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="BeginToday9" style="height: 500px; text-align: center; margin-top: 0;">

</div>
```

Regards
Satanshu Mishra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that looks like you are requesting. N.B. the second shape is just another rectangle that is slid under the skewed rectangle.
https://jsfiddle.net/055Ltymg/

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="A">
</div>
<div id="B">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#A {
    background-color: #2ECC71;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0px 50px;
    position: relative;
    transform: skewY(5deg);
    z-index: 2
}
#B {
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px dotted blue;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: That Help's Thanks a Lot